# Using LEAD and LAG with an unknown number of rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with information about service involvement for a group of people as in the code below, which I am running in Oracle.

```
CREATE TABLE SRVC_EPISODES
(
   CASE_INDEX        NUMBER (10),
   CLIENT_ID         NUMBER (10),
   SRVC_ID           NUMBER (10),
   SRVC_START_DT     DATE,
   SRVC_END_DT       DATE,
   SRVC_END_REASON   VARCHAR2 (70 BYTE)
);

INSERT INTO SRVC_EPISODES VALUES (1, 1, 3747, TO_DATE('03/28/2017', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), TO_DATE('06/27/2017', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 'Full Completion');
INSERT INTO SRVC_EPISODES VALUES (2, 1, 5231, TO_DATE('02/16/2018', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), TO_DATE('06/30/2018', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 'Service Transfer');
INSERT INTO SRVC_EPISODES VALUES (3, 1, 3929, TO_DATE('07/01/2018', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), TO_DATE('07/01/2018', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 'Service Transfer');
INSERT INTO SRVC_EPISODES VALUES (4, 1, 6688, TO_DATE('07/13/2018', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), TO_DATE('10/19/2018', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 'Full Completion');
INSERT INTO SRVC_EPISODES VALUES (5, 2, 73, TO_DATE('10/03/2017', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), TO_DATE('06/30/2018', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 'Service Transfer');
INSERT INTO SRVC_EPISODES VALUES (6, 2, 201, TO_DATE('05/07/2018', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), TO_DATE('06/30/2018', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 'Service Transfer');
INSERT INTO SRVC_EPISODES VALUES (7, 2, 8102, TO_DATE('06/02/2018', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), TO_DATE('06/30/2018', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 'Service Transfer');
INSERT INTO SRVC_EPISODES VALUES (8, 2, 4164, TO_DATE('07/01/2018', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), TO_DATE('03/20/2019', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 'Incomplete');
INSERT INTO SRVC_EPISODES VALUES (9, 2, 2066, TO_DATE('07/01/2018', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), TO_DATE('12/02/2019', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 'Failed Classes');
```

An issue that I am encountering is that often times, an individual will transfer providers mid-way through their service, as indicated by differing SRVC_IDs and the preceding SRVC_END_REASON, when sorting by CLIENT_ID --> SRVC_START_DT --> SRVC_END_DT.

In the example below, CLIENT_ID #1 has two distinct service episodes - one which took place from 3/28/2017 - 6/27/2017 which they successfully completed. Their next service however, took place with three different providers (three distinct service IDs), and took place from 2/16/2018 to 10/19/2018, which they also successfully completed.

CLIENT_ID #4 also has two distinct service episodes. The first took place from 10/3/2017 and ended on 3/20/2019 with an incomplete. Their next service episode took place from 7/1/2018 to 12/2/2019, which they failed. Even though this might be hard to see, CASE_INDEX #9 is a different service as the preceding service  did not have 'transfer' as a service end reason (grouped by CLIENT_ID, then sorted by SRVC_START_DT, then SRVC_END_DT).

I'd say the biggest issue that I am running into is that the number of transfers for each client is not fixed, if they have any transfers at all. If we need to, lets assume that maximum number of transfers would be 5.

I know that the solution to this involves using lead/lag, but I after much struggle I can't figure out how. My end goal is to have correct SRVC_START_DT, SRVC_END_DT, and SRVC_END_REASON as in the example below.

[image: Data Example]

Comment: Is "provider" somehow represented in your data?  It is not obvious.

Comment: Unfortunately not. The provider name is not relevant, at least as far as I can tell. We identify distinct service episodes through SRVC_ID

Comment: I don't get it.  How, from the data in the table, do you know that there are 2 service episodes for client #1?  Because of specific phrases in SRVC_END_REASON?

Comment: Yup. Sorry if that was unclear. This is all predicated on sorting first by client ID, then SRVC_START_DT and then SRVC_END_DT

Comment: So is the rule "if SRVC_END_REASON is one of Full Completion, Incomplete, Failed Classes then this is the end of the service episode"?

Comment: Yup. Although I would probably state the rule as if SRVC_END_REASON NOT LIKE '%Transfer%', as that'll capture all the other end reason (which there are a bunch in reality).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to do it (along with a couple of extra columns you can dispense with):

```
select v2.*
,      min(srvc_start_dt) over (partition by grp order by srvc_start_dt) new_start_dt
,      max(srvc_end_dt)    over (partition by grp order by srvc_start_dt desc) new_end_dt
,      first_value(srvc_end_reason) over (partition by grp order by srvc_start_dt desc) new_end_reason
from (
  select v.*
  ,     sum(stat) over(order by client_id desc, srvc_start_dt desc, srvc_end_dt desc) grp 
  from (
    select s.*
    ,      case when srvc_end_reason not like '%Transfer%' then 1 end as stat
    from   SRVC_EPISODES s
  ) v
) v2
order by 1;
```

Comment: You are a saint Tony. Thank you so so so so so much. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Partly for my own amusement and curiosity/learning, you could also do this with [`match_recognize`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DWHSG/pattern.htm) (12c+):

```
select case_index, client_id, srvc_id, srvc_start_dt, srvc_end_dt, srvc_end_reason,
  new_start_dt, new_end_dt, new_end_reason
from srvc_episodes
match_recognize (
  partition by client_id
  order by srvc_start_dt, srvc_end_dt
  measures
    first(srvc_start_dt) as new_start_dt,
    final last(srvc_end_dt) as new_end_dt,
    final last(srvc_end_reason) as new_end_reason
  all rows per match
  after match skip past last row
  pattern (complete | transfer+ complete)
  define
    transfer as transfer.srvc_end_reason = 'Service Transfer',
    complete as complete.srvc_end_reason != 'Service Transfer'
)
order by case_index;

CASE_INDEX  CLIENT_ID    SRVC_ID SRVC_START SRVC_END_D SRVC_END_REASON      NEW_START_ NEW_END_DT NEW_END_REASON      
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- -------------------- ---------- ---------- --------------------
         1          1       3747 2017-03-28 2017-06-27 Full Completion      2017-03-28 2017-06-27 Full Completion     
         2          1       5231 2018-02-16 2018-06-30 Service Transfer     2018-02-16 2018-10-19 Full Completion     
         3          1       3929 2018-07-01 2018-07-01 Service Transfer     2018-02-16 2018-10-19 Full Completion     
         4          1       6688 2018-07-13 2018-10-19 Full Completion      2018-02-16 2018-10-19 Full Completion     
         5          2         73 2017-10-03 2018-06-30 Service Transfer     2017-10-03 2019-03-20 Incomplete          
         6          2        201 2018-05-07 2018-06-30 Service Transfer     2017-10-03 2019-03-20 Incomplete          
         7          2       8102 2018-06-02 2018-06-30 Service Transfer     2017-10-03 2019-03-20 Incomplete          
         8          2       4164 2018-07-01 2019-03-20 Incomplete           2017-10-03 2019-03-20 Incomplete          
         9          2       2066 2018-07-01 2019-12-02 Failed Classes       2018-07-01 2019-12-02 Failed Classes
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9e906ff1f5d18674ac05af03c6af4a7b)